# MySQL - Perl- Order by - How to display ABS(PartNum) DESC but, three different (PartNum) categories?

Tags: mysql, perl, sorting

Sorry for my inaccurate syntax. New to this.

I need to select part numbers in three different groups.

A different qty for each group.

Each group individually sorted ABS desc.

```
my $fromrow = CGI::param('from');## vague but put here to show a sort of pagination  ## 
my $nextrow = CGI::param('next');
my $grabpartnumbers = $hookup->prepare(qq{
   SELECT `New`,`Used`,`NOS`,`PartNum`,`Description`,`Price`
   FROM `Partstable`
   WHERE `instock` = ? AND `QTY` > ? AND `New` = ?
   ORDER BY ABS(PartNum) LIMIT ?,?});
$grabpartnumbers->execute('1','10','1',$fromrow,$nextrow);
while(@row = $grabpartnumbers->fetchrow_array()) {
#do stuff
```

Works fine, for one "column" eg "New". 
However, I want to display like:

New Stock
4 results

NOS
6 results

Used Stock
10 results

Additional problems will arise for me when one of the three "columns" have no more data to display. At that point, I just want to display the remaining result or nothing (not even the title header) if results = 0 for that cat.

Is this possible or do I need to prepare three different queries and possibly push each into their own arrays to decipher what to display in some loops?

This is VERY advanced for me so, please be verbose with examples. (dumb it down to my level of comprehension (-; )

Thanks..

EDIT:

My Partstable rows look like

```
   ID|PartNum|New|Used|NOS|Qty|instock|Description|Price
    1|132452 |1  |0   |0  | 24|y      |12ax7 yada |3.00
```

I want to display three "areas" on the same page by order of "importance". "New" take priority.

New Stock 4 results

NOS 6 results

Used Stock 10 results

Comment: Please clarify what you want. You seem to be confusing rows with columns. What is the table structure like? Can you give an example? Is your problem solved by an `if` in the loop, checking if the results are zero before printing?

Comment: This is very advanced for me too, Are you storing `New,Used,NOS` as columns & want to return them as 3 separate rows?

Comment: In order for us to have a better idea of what you are looking for, can you edit your question and include at the bottom a "table(s)" of how you would like the results to be pulled, because this: New Stock 4 results

NOS 6 results

Used Stock 10 results

", doesn't seem to make sense in context of your code snippet and what you have said you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to achieve is a little bit difficult to precisely comprehend, but it looks like you could potentially be just fine with a full-SQL solution (clever use of `GROUP BY`, etc.).

Regarding the current solution with Perl, and assuming I understand your example correctly, something like this would work as a starting point for you to play around and adapt to your actual dataset.

*Warning: Code tested against syntax only!*

```
my $fromrow = CGI::param('from');## vague but put here to show a sort of pagination  ## 
my $nextrow = CGI::param('next');

# Columns of interest, sorted by descending order of importance
my @interesting_columns = qw(
    New
    Used
    NOS
    PartNum
    Description
    Price
);

my $interesting_columns_expr = join(', ', map { $_ = "`$_`" } @interesting_columns);
my $grabpartnumbers = $hookup->prepare(qq{
    SELECT $interesting_columns_expr
    FROM `Partstable`
    WHERE `instock` = ? AND `QTY` > ? 
    ORDER BY ABS(PartNum) LIMIT ?,?
});
$grabpartnumbers->execute('1','10',$fromrow,$nextrow);

# Compute results
my %result_counter;
while ( my $row = $grabpartnumbers->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
    foreach my $column_name ( keys %$row ) {
        $result_counter{$column_name} += $row->{$column_name};
    }
}

# Display results
for my $column_name ( @interesting_columns ) {
    if (exists $result_counter{$column_name}) {
        print join( ':', $column_name, $result_counter{$column_name} );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand this to a point. I will play with this tonight and pick your brain a little tomorrow should I get stuck. I will happily check as answered when I decipher bit. Looks like I will need to set some count vars in there though to get the counts I need. Very advanced but, I do understand some of it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, this is useful but, I cannot get the results I need as I am not capable of modifying this to my needs. Totally my weakness so, I will have to display data differently. Thanks so much for this, I have placed this in my cheat sheet for the future I will become advanced enough to manipulate.

Comment: @Stephie, I would be happy to help again if you can break down your needs more precisely in another question! In the meantime, I would like to suggest the reading of two books that saved my life when I was learning Perl. 1- The Perl Cookbook (ISBN-13 978-0596003135) 2- Effective Perl Programming (ISBN-13 978-0321496942). And I would also add 3- Moderl Perl (available online at http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/). Good luck!